# Using asyncawait module with function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the module [asyncawait](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asyncawait) (because my node version isn't high enough on the server to use the real async/await). 
I have the following function which uses the await function:

```
function getNextParticipant(req, res) {
    let nextThreeUsers = await(getNextThreeUsersInQueue())
    // other things done here
}
```

Before I had this function as part of an Express router endpoint, and I wrapped it in `async(...)` like this:

```
router.get('/getNextParticipant', async((req, res) => {
    let nextThreeUsers = await(getNextThreeUsersInQueue())
    // other things done here
}))
```

but I want to use this on multiple endpoints. So I'm attempting to call it like this:

```
router.get('/getNextParticipant', (req, res) => {
    return async (getNextParticipant(req, res))
})
```

This doesn't seem to work... What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: `This doesn't seem to work` what didn't work? Any relevant errors you can add that would help?

Comment: You cannot use `await` in a function that is not declared as `async` and `getNextParticipant` is not defined as `async`

Comment: You are also using `async` instead of `await` in the middleware callback example where you should have the middleware callback itself be `async` and the internal promise-returning call be `await`-ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing getNextParticipant to look like this, then it worked:

```
var getNextParticipant = async((req, res) => {
    // ...
})
```